# Android Preferences in second Activity

Tags: android, preferences

I have added some button to main activity. 
When using a button you will open an activity.

In main activity

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SettingsActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

In that new activity i want to put the preferences of android.

```
  public class SettingsActivity extends MainActivity {..}
```

The problem is that i need to extend PreferencesActivity. I have already extend my main activity.

What should i do to make this happen?

Comment: Why would you need extend your MainActivity anyways?

Comment: I dont needed after all. I am new at Android and make stupid mistakes

Answer (score 0):

delete `MainActivity` then write in the extension that you wanted.

Comment: This does not help. The settings activity crashes

Comment: ok my bad, i forgot to change the addPreferencesFromResource.